# Should I declare "var" variables in an Angular controller or always use $scope

Tags: angularjs

If I have a controller such as:

```
myApp.controller('NewController', function ($scope, $window) {
   var x = 5;
   $scope.y = 5;
});
```

And `x` and `y` are going to be changed from my application, does it make any difference whether or not I declare `var x` on `$scope` or just declare it with `var` as it is right now?

Comment: Yes, it does make a difference. Someone looking at your code needs to know which are internal "private" variables and which are exposed as "public" on your view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$scope is just the glue between your rendered view and your controller. If you don't need the variable in your view, then don't add it to the $scope object.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends upon the application that you are developing. If one wishes to bind the `variables` with that of the `view` via the `controller`, then `$scope` is preferred. Otherwise, when the variable is meant for some internal functionality only, then one should use JavaScript's `var` as it will not hinder the performance when making use of AngularJS framework, by adding unnecessary variables that aren't required at all for either for two-way binding or one-way binding.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use new ControllerAs syntax and not to use $scope at all:

```
myApp.controller('NewController', function ($scope, $window) {
    this.y = 5;
});
```

for native JS it's pretty clear that you don't need var before "this", right?

Comment: this should not work if I use a router and never declare ng-controller="" in my views no?

Answer (score 0):

It's depands on you if you bind the value with any html dom that should be change when you are changing your model then you should use $scope. otherwise you can use var and $scope. but now in angular 2.0 $scope has removed.